# Asterisk: strange thing happen with this dialplan

Tags: asterisk

I have a ISDN phone connect to a Digium b410p card.
Is working fine but there are some strange thing with the dialplan, with this simple dialplan

```
[from-dahdi]
exten => 1796522,1,Dial(DAHDI/g12/${EXTEN})
exten => 1796522,2,Hangup()

exten => s,1,Wait(10)
exten => s,2,Answer
exten => s,3,Dial(DAHDI/g12/${EXTEN})

[local]
;
; Master context for local, toll-free, and iaxtel calls only
;
include => default
include => from-dahdi

exten => 600,1,Playback(demo-echotest) ; Let them know what’s going on
exten => 600,2,Echo ; Do the echo test
exten => 600,3,Playback(demo-echodone) ; Let them know it’s over
```

When I call the 600, i have to answer by my own phone(i call 600 but my phone said there is a call from my own number 1796522!) and if I answer I hear the music.

If I remove the line     exten => s,3,Dial(DAHDI/g12/${EXTEN}) the call return me a timeout
What I miss?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution found:

I edit `/etc/asterisk/chan_dahdi.conf` adding/modify those lines.

```
overlapdial=yes
immediate=no
```

Now the file is like this, maybe can be useful for someone

```
[trunkgroups]
[channels]
language=it
context=local
switchtype=euroisdn
overlapdial=yes
signalling=bri_net_ptmp
usecallerid=yes
callwaiting=yes
usecallingpres=yes
callwaitingcallerid=yes
threewaycalling=yes
transfer=yes
canpark=yes
cancallforward=yes
callreturn=yes
context=local
echocancel=yes
channel => 1,2,4,5,7,8,10,11
echocancelwhenbridged=yes
group=1
callgroup=1
pickupgroup=1
immediate=no
#include /etc/asterisk/dahdi-channels.conf
```

Now the isdn phone can call the internal numbers